# How to setup Swagger to have only one Authorize and Close buttons in ASP.NET Core 8 app?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8

I have setup Swagger to request two fields for authentication. Both fields are equally important and I need both of them to be sent in the headers as part of authentication. Not just either of them.

Can someone suggest how to correct the setup to have only one instance of Authorize and Close buttons?

[Printscreen of Authorization Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkoWC.png)

Here is the code I call to setup Swagger at the moment.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
{ 
   SwaggerHelper.SetupSwaggerVwAuthentication(c, "OT Trading Service API"); 
});
```

This is the `SetupSwaggerVwAuthentication` method:

```cs
public static void SetupSwaggerVwAuthentication(SwaggerGenOptions swaggerGenOptions, string serviceName)
{
    swaggerGenOptions.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = serviceName, Version = "v1" });
    swaggerGenOptions.AddSecurityDefinition(HeaderConstants.VwToken, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
       {
           Name = HeaderConstants.VwToken,
           Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
           In = ParameterLocation.Header,
           Scheme = GlobalConstants.VwAuthentication
       });
    swaggerGenOptions.AddSecurityDefinition(HeaderConstants.UserName, new OpenApiSecurityScheme
       {
           Name = HeaderConstants.UserName,
           Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
           In = ParameterLocation.Header,
           Scheme = GlobalConstants.VwAuthentication
       });

    swaggerGenOptions.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
       {
           {
               new OpenApiSecurityScheme
               {
                   Reference = new OpenApiReference
                   {
                       Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                       Id = HeaderConstants.VwToken
                   }
               },
               new List<string>()
           },
           {
               new OpenApiSecurityScheme
               {
                   Reference = new OpenApiReference
                   {
                       Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                       Id = HeaderConstants.UserName
                   }
               },
               new List<string>()
           }
       });
}
```

Comment: Please see this link for help: https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/assign-specific-authorization-scheme-to-endpoint-in-swagger-ui-in-net-core-cd84d2a2ebd7